# get image from ImageView to another imageView in second activity when click on 1st imageview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

I want to get image from ImageView to another imageView in second activity when click on 1st imageview

This Is My 1st Activity

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fort_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.killa_ahmednagar_bhuikot_fort);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullscreenImageActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

I Want That Image Into Second Full Screen Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Activity 1**:

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fort_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.killa_ahmednagar_bhuikot_fort);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullscreenImageActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("Drawable", R.drawable.killa_ahmednagar_bhuikot_fort);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

In **Activity 2**:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int drawable = intent.getIntExtra("Drawable", 0); 
    imageView.setImageResource(drawable);
```

Comment: YES, Great. That Works For Me..Thank You So Much

Comment: In Same 

If i have Two ImageView. how to i determine which imageview is clicked to get that image into next activity.

Comment: Attach onlick listener to both of your imageviews then both onlick functions   send their drawables. like this **For ImageView1:** `myIntent.putExtra("Drawable", R.drawable.drawable_of_image1);` and for **ImageView2:** `myIntent.putExtra("Drawable", R.drawable..drawable_of_image2);`

Cheers. If your problem is solved, marked this as correct answer